# Django access to language code in filter function

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have some list of items in django template and I loop over this list to build a table od my records.
In one of fields I have a dictionary key (int from 1 to 12). I wrote a filter to change key integers for a good looking names. I would like to check what is currently user language before filter returns. It is possible to check language code in filter/tag function in Django?

This is my loop in template:

```
{% for field in fields_list %}
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-padding-5"><div class="cart-tab-row">{{ forloop.counter }}</div></div>
    <div class="col-padding-5"><div class="cart-tab-row">{{ field.field_name }}</div></div>
    <div class="col-padding-5"><div class="cart-tab-row">{{ trans field.c_type|get_cname }}</div></div>
    <div class="col-padding-5"><div class="cart-tab-row">{{ field.area|floatformat:2 }}</div></div>
    <div class="col-padding-5"><div class="cart-tab-row">{{ field.price|floatformat:2 }}</div></div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my filter function

```
@register.filter
def get_cname(key):
    ctype = CesTypesDict.objects.filter(id=key)[0]
    return ctype.english_type_name
```

In normal view I access this information from request attribute, but in filter I don't have access to request object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django makes the language of the current request-response cycle globally available via the [`get_language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.get_language) function. So you do not need the request object:

```
from django.utils.translation import get_language

@register.filter
def get_cname(key):
    # ...
    language_code = get_language()
    # do stuff with language_code
    return ...
```

Comment: It works for me :)  But in my case import should be  `django.utils.translation import get_language`